# Cannot read property 'nid' of undefined, need to pass object to another controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, undefined

I'm having issues trying to pass a selected value from one controller to another controller.

View (I pass the NgValue to $scope in Controller).

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in filterData = (informes | filter:{title:searchTitle, resolucion:searchReso, year: searchYear}) | limitTo:10:10*(currentPage-1)">
                     <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="informes" ng-value="nodeID(item)">
                          <a ng-href="../node-informes/node-informes.html">
                            <p class="text-center text-truncate">
                               <small>{{item.title}}</small>
                            </p>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Controller. I have the "Item in that Controller" and the console prints it.

```
informes.controller('InformesCtrl', ['drupal', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', 'InformesFtry', function(drupal, $rootScope, $scope, $http, InformesFtry) {
      $rootScope.getData = function(informes){
          $rootScope.nodeID = function(item){
              $rootScope.node = item.nid;
              console.log($rootScope.node);
          };       
      }
}]);
```

2nd Controller in another module (gives me "Cannot read property 'nid' of undefined" error").

```
nodeInformes.controller('NodeInformesCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$controller', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $controller) {
  $controller('InformesCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
  $rootScope.getData(informes);
  $rootScope.nodeID(item);
  $scope.node = $rootScope.node;
  console.log($scope.node);
}]);
```

It supposed that i called the other controller with parameters (saved value in "$rootScope.node", passed it to 2nd controller, but it gives me the error that's undefined).

consolelog in first controller works, but not in second controller.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Modified as code suggested, but seems that the "item" object is not passing the right way.

Comment: It's not a variable name problem, could be, but not in this case (Tried that). For me i'm binding data the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using `$rootScope` unless you absolutely have to (raising or handling events is about the only time I've ever used `$rootScope`) - instead you can use a service to reliably pass data between controllers. In AngularJS services are singletons so all of your controllers have access to the same instance. You can take advantage of this and use the service to "pass" (more accurately share) data between controllers.

Here is a simple example to demonstrate the concept which you can then apply to your situation. Normally you wouldn't have two controllers in a single view like this, but for illustration purposes (and being able to run in the SO snippet engine) I've done it here. Just to prove that I'm not sharing any controller variables I've named them differently.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .service('sharedService', function() {
    var service = {};
    service.sharedObject = {};
    service.sharedObject.value = "Set in service";
    return service;
  })
  .controller('ctrlOne', function($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.sharedObjectC1 = sharedService.sharedObject;
  })
  .controller('ctrlTwo', function($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.sharedObjectC2 = sharedService.sharedObject;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrlOne" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
    <h1>Controller One</h1>
    Modifying this value will update it in Controller Two:
    <div>
      <input ng-model="sharedObjectC1.value" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="ctrlTwo">
    <h1>Controller Two</h1>
    Modifying this value will update it in Controller One:
    <div>
      <input ng-model="sharedObjectC2.value" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Haven't tried yet. But yes, you have the point, forgot to create service and now it's working better.  I will post feedback in the update. Thanks!!!